# How to know Android OS mobile is landscape or portrait when orientation fixed to portrait in manifest file

Tags: android, screen, sensormanager

In my Business card reader application, I fixed screen orientation in my first camera capture activity, now I want to know orientation is landScape or portrait.
I use SensorManager but it will give most of time landscape when just small change angle of mobile.

here screenOrientation=0 when Landscape

and screenOrientation=1 when Portrait

```
private void registerAccelerometerSensor() {
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER)) {
        eventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (event.values[1] < 6.5 && event.values[1] > -6.5) {
                    if (orientation != 1) {
                        Log.d("Sensor", "Landscape");
                        screenOrientation = 0;
                    }

                } else {
                    if (orientation != 0) {
                        Log.d("Sensor", "Portrait");
                        screenOrientation = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
        sensorManager.registerListener(eventListener,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    } else {
        screenOrientation = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380989/how-do-i-get-the-current-orientation-activityinfo-screen-orientation-of-an-a

Comment: @Segi, here my application i fixed orientation as Portrait in manifestfile ,but i want know screen is landscape or Portrait when user changes angle of mobile.

Answer (score 1):

See some sample code here:

```
public int getScreenOrientation() {
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getRotation();
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
                || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        } else {
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
        }
    }
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
                || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        } else {
            return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
        }
    }
    return ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED;
}
```

Comment: That will not work because orientation has been locked so regardless of how the user orientates the device you will always get same fixed value orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT