# How to lock screen orientation in reverse portrait and reverse landscape mode

Tags: android, screen-orientation

```
int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        } else if(currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
```

This is the code is used for locking screen orientation programatically. But it is not working for reverse portrait and reverse landscape. What could be the solution.

Comment: have you tried in xml?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get current orientation in constants of `ActivityInfo` class

```
private int getScreenOrientation() {
    int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;
    int orientation;
    // if the device's natural orientation is portrait:
    if ((rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) && height > width ||
        (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270) && width > height) {
        switch(rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " +
                        "portrait.");
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;              
        }
    }
    // if the device's natural orientation is landscape or if the device
    // is square:
    else {
        switch(rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                orientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unknown screen orientation. Defaulting to " +
                        "landscape.");
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
                break;              
        }
    }

    return orientation;
}
```

How to use in your case:

```
setRequestedOrientation(getScreenOrientation());
```

If it was usefull, please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383164/1659629) answer

Comment: you should not copy paste code from other answers that you did not write. flag as duplicate if needed.