# Current horizontal or vertical screen

Tags: android

If I have created an Android app and I use a emulator.
I would to know If I use horizontal or vertical screen by using java code.

Is there a syntax that gives a feedback if current situation if horcontal or vertical screen?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380989/how-do-i-get-the-current-orientation-activityinfo-screen-orientation-of-an-a

Answer (score 0):

You may obtain current orientation from resources 
`context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`

Note that there are 4 posiible values: landscape, portrait, undefined and square (deprecated since API level 16)

Comment: Thank you for your help! How about API 15?

Comment: Im using api 15

Comment: So you can use provided code `context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`. It works since API 1.