# I want to know the screen orientation of the phone

Tags: android

Can I check if the screen of the phone is facing up or down?

I want to receive events when the phone is turned upside down and normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    // code for portrait mode
} else {
    // code for landscape mode
}
```

Answer [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28910214/7765316)

and check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383164/7765316) for knowing the rotation